# Python Greedy Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, greedy

I am writing a greedy algorithm (Python 3.x.x) for a 'jewel heist'. Given a series of jewels and values, the program grabs the most valuable jewel that it can fit in it's bag without going over the bag weight limit. I've got three test cases here, and it works perfectly for two of them.

Each test case is written in the same way: first line is the bag weight limit, all lines following are tuples(weight, value).

Sample Case 1 (works):

```
10
3 4
2 3
1 1
```

Sample Case 2 (doesn't work):

```
575
125 3000
50 100
500 6000
25 30
```

Code:

```
def take_input(infile):
    f_open = open(infile, 'r')
    lines = []
    for line in f_open:
        lines.append(line.strip())
    f_open.close()
    return lines

def set_weight(weight):
    bag_weight = weight
    return bag_weight

def jewel_list(lines):
    jewels = []
    for item in lines:
        jewels.append(item.split())
    jewels = sorted(jewels, reverse= True)
    jewel_dict = {}
    for item in jewels:
        jewel_dict[item[1]] = item[0]
    return jewel_dict

def greedy_grab(weight_max, jewels):
    #first, we get a list of values
    values = []
    weights = []
    for keys in jewels:
        weights.append(jewels[keys])
    for item in jewels.keys():
        values.append(item)
    values = sorted(values, reverse= True)
    #then, we start working
    max = int(weight_max)
    running = 0
    i = 0
    grabbed_list = []
    string = ''
    total_haul = 0
    # pick the most valuable item first. Pick as many of them as you can.            
    # Then, the next, all the way through.
    while running < max:
        next_add = int(jewels[values[i]])
        if (running + next_add) > max:
            i += 1
        else:
            running += next_add
            grabbed_list.append(values[i])
    for item in grabbed_list:
        total_haul += int(item)
    string = "The greedy approach would steal $" + str(total_haul) + " of  
             jewels."
    return string

infile = "JT_test2.txt"
lines = take_input(infile)
#set the bag weight with the first line from the input
bag_max = set_weight(lines[0])
#once we set bag weight, we don't need it anymore
lines.pop(0)

#generate a list of jewels in a dictionary by weight, value
value_list = jewel_list(lines)
#run the greedy approach
print(greedy_grab(bag_max, value_list))
```

Does anyone have any clues why it wouldn't work for case 2? Your help is greatly appreciated.
**EDIT: The expected outcome for case 2 is $6130. I seem to get $6090.**

Comment: What is the expected output in case2, and what is the observed output for case2?

Comment: Expected: $6130
Actual: $6090

Comment: You should really edit that information into your post, so that everyone can see. Also, what is the observed result?

Comment: Also, please fix the indentation in your code. Paste your code, then click on the `{}` button just above the text box, to do so.

Comment: Sounds like the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dictionary keys are strings, not integers so they are sorted like string when you try to sort them. So you would get:

```
['6000', '3000', '30', '100']
```

instead wanted:

```
['6000', '3000', '100', '30']
```

Change this function to be like this and to have integer keys:

```
def jewel_list(lines):
    jewels = []
    for item in lines:
        jewels.append(item.split())
    jewels = sorted(jewels, reverse= True)
    jewel_dict = {}
    for item in jewels:
        jewel_dict[int(item[1])] = item[0]  # changed line
    return jewel_dict
```

When you change this it will give you:

```
The greedy approach would steal $6130 of jewels.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [237]: %paste
def greedy(infilepath):
  with open(infilepath) as infile:
    capacity = int(infile.readline().strip())
    items = [map(int, line.strip().split()) for line in infile]

  bag = []
  items.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
  while capacity and items:
    if items[-1][0] <= capacity:
      bag.append(items[-1])
      capacity -= items[-1][0]
    items.pop()
  return bag

## -- End pasted text --

In [238]: sum(map(operator.itemgetter(1), greedy("JT_test1.txt")))
Out[238]: 8

In [239]: sum(map(operator.itemgetter(1), greedy("JT_test2.txt")))
Out[239]: 6130
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this piece of code `i` has to be incremented on the else side too

```
while running < max:
  next_add = int(jewels[values[i]])
  if (running + next_add) > max:
    i += 1
  else:
    running += next_add
    grabbed_list.append(values[i])
    i += 1 #here
```

this and @iblazevic's answer explains why it behaves this way

Comment: Wouldn't incrementing it on that part of the while loop stop it from being a greedy algorithm? I want it to keep picking that high value jewel until it satisfies the first if statement, and then iterate past that to the next in the list. I think your way would only allow me to pick that jewel once, if I'm correct.

Comment: oh, ok, i thought that you can only pick them once

Comment: you could do something like `running += (max-running) / value*value`